# Using Jquery not able to get correct out put

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I did a small style changing app using Jquery in Asp.Net 3.5 .I am having IE7.
When i click on button the paragraph color should change.
Problem is ,the color is changing,it is not stable.Means just like blinking.
Please find the code below

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#Button1").click(function() {

                $("p").css("background-color", "Yellow")

            });

        });

    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            <p>This Should be in  <br/>
               yellow</p>

           </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because ASP.NET changes the ID attribute to be something it can resolve.

If you are using ASP.NET 4, set the `ClientIDMode` to `AutoID`.

If you are using anything else, change your selector to use `"#<%= Button1.ClientID %>"`

Also, return `false` to prevent the form from being postbacked.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
        $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").click(function() {

            $("p").css("background-color", "Yellow")

        });
```

When the Button renders on the client it won't have id = "Button1"

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$("#Button1").click(function() {
```

to

```
$("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[id$='Button1']").click(function() {
button click stuff here.
});
```